# Rudin Proposition 1.18(c)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand Rudin's proof of part (c) of Propositon 1.18. These statements concern ordered fields.

> 1.18 (c) If $x < 0$ and $y < z$ then $xy > xz$.

The results Rudin suggests using are:

> 1.18 (a) If $x > 0$ then $-x < 0$ and vice versa.

> 1.18 (b) If $x > 0$ and $y < z$ then $xy < xz$.

> 1.16 (c) $(-x)y = -(xy) = x(-y)$.

Here is my attempt. I am trying to follow Rudin's steps, but it's possible that I haven't quite understood his proof. (I've written that up below to compare it to my proof.)

> **My proof.** By part (a), since $x < 0$, $-x > 0$. Since $y < z$. $z - y > 0$. By property (II) of ordered fields, we have $(-x)(z - y) > 0$. By applying 1.16(c) with $z - y$ in place of $y$, we have
> $$(-x)(z - y) = -[x(z-y)].$$
> So $-[x(z - y)] > 0$. By part (a), $x(z-y) < 0$. By distributivity, this implies $xz - xy < 0$. Adding $xy$ to both sides, using associativity of addition and then using the additive inverse and additive identity axiom, we have  $xz < xy$.

Below is Rudin's proof.

> By (a), (b), and Proposition 1.16(c),
> $$-[x(z-y)] = (-x)(z - y) > 0$$
> so that $x(z-y) < 0$, hence $xz < xy$.

Rudin's proof is much shorter than mine, to say the least. Have I replicated his proof correctly? Are there any holes in my above proof?

Comment: Rudin's writing is usually short

Comment: Your argument is fine.

Comment: You proof is sound and is basically the same are rudin's but with everything explained.  Rudin assumes it will be clear in a single line why $-[x(x-y)]=(-x)(z-y)$ and why $(-x)(z-y)>0$.  You spell it out in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, you filled in all the details which Rudin omitted.

However, I think if we follow Rudins's advice to use (a), (b), and Proposition 1.16(c), then we should argue as follows:

1. Since $x < 0$, $-x > 0$ by (a).
2. Since $-x > 0$ and $y < z$, $(-x)y < (-x)z$ by (b).
3. This shows $-(xy) < -(xz)$ by 1.16(c).
4. Adding $xy + xz$ on both sides gives $xz < yz$.

Comment: That's how I would do it.  But given Rudins actual one line proof which uses the expression $(-x)(y-z)$ I think the OP has actually done it the way Rudin intended (which is not what have occurred to me to do).

Comment: @fleablood Yes. As I said, the OP filled in all the details which Rudin omitted. Rudin's proof is absolutely correct, but **why** he argues as he does is unclear to me. In fact, he invokes an additional step: Since $y < z$, we have $w = z-y > 0$ and (b) is applied to the special case $-x > 0$ and $w > 0$.